# /usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -larchives

Tags: linux, spring, compilation

I am trying to comiple spring on 64-bit Linux Mint 14 and get the following error:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../../spring
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -larchives
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -larchives
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [spring] Error 1
make[2]: *** [rts/builds/default/CMakeFiles/engine-default.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [rts/builds/default/CMakeFiles/spring.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [spring] Error 2
```

I am following the instructions at: http://springrts.com/wiki/Building_Spring_on_Linux
but don't understand the error. Any suggestions?

NOTE: I am cloning the repo git://github.com/spring/spring.git and rolling back to tag 91.0 to allow online game play.

Comment: You need some shared library like `libarchives.so.*` or maybe some static library like `libarchives.a` and you may want to add more `-Llibdir/` flags

Comment: I'm not entirely sure which static library or how to import the static library.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following work-around to resolve the dependency issue:

Instead of cloning the git repository, I downloaded a tarball containing the latest snapshot (in my case: spring_94.1_src.tar.lzma) see: http://springrts.com/wiki/Download#Latest_Stable_Snapshot

No errors were reported when compiling the tarball code.